# JedisPoolConfig is not assignable to GenericObjectPoolConfig

Tags: java, spring, caching, redis, jedis

I have a Spring based java web application hosted on Heroku.  I am attempting to utilize the Spring Caching abstraction using the Redis implementation.  When the server starts, I get an error saying:

```
Type 'redis/clients/jedis/JedisPoolConfig' (current frame, stack[3]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/GenericObjectPoolConfig'
```

### Here is my configuration:

```
@Bean
     RedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() throws Exception {
         URI redisUri =  new URI(System.getenv("REDISCLOUD_URL"));
         JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
         redisConnectionFactory.setHostName(redisUri.getHost());
         redisConnectionFactory.setPort(redisUri.getPort());
         redisConnectionFactory.setPassword(redisUri.getUserInfo().split(":",2)[1]);
         redisConnectionFactory.setUsePool(true);
         return redisConnectionFactory;
     }

 @Bean
 RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate()  {
     RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<Object, Object>();
     try {
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     return redisTemplate;
 }
@Override
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    // configure and return an implementation of Spring's CacheManager SPI
    RedisCacheManager manager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate());
    List<String> caches = new ArrayList<String>();
    caches.add("Suppliers");
    caches.add("Manufacturer");
    caches.add("Sheeting");
    caches.add("SignTypeFlat");
    manager.setCacheNames(caches);
    return manager;
}
```

### Here is the entire Error Message:

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory m ethod [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory com.signInventory.config.ProdDataSourceConfiguration.jedisConnectionFactory() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack Exception Details:   Location:
    org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet()V @109: invokespecial   Reason:
    Type 'redis/clients/jedis/JedisPoolConfig' (current frame, stack[3]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/GenericObjectPoolConfig'   Current Frame:
    bci: @109
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisConnectionFactory' }
    stack: { 'org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisConnectionFactory', uninitialized 73, uninitialized 73, 'redis/clients/jedis/JedisPoolConfig', 'java/lang/String', integer, integer, 'java/lang/String' }   Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab4 000d c700 3d2a bb00 1759 2ab4 0003
    0000010: 2ab4 0004 b700 18b5 000d 2ab4 0019 b800
    0000020: 1a99 000e 2ab4 000d 2ab4 0019 b600 1b2a
    0000030: b400 059e 000e 2ab4 000d 2ab4 0005 b600
    0000040: 1c2a b400 0699 002e 2abb 001d 592a b400
    0000050: 0a2a b400 0db6 001e 2ab4 000d b600 1f2a
    0000060: b400 0db6 0020 2ab4 000d b600 21b7 0022
    0000070: b500 07b1   Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@47)
    same_frame(@65)
    same_frame(@115) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:578) ... 36 more Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack Exception Details:   Location:
    org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet()V @109: invokespecial   Reason:
    Type 'redis/clients/jedis/JedisPoolConfig' (current frame, stack[3]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/GenericObjectPoolConfig'   Current Frame:
    bci: @109
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisConnectionFactory' }
    stack: { 'org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisConnectionFactory', uninitialized 73, uninitialized 73, 'redis/clients/jedis/JedisPoolConfig', 'java/lang/String', integer, integer, 'java/lang/String' }   Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab4 000d c700 3d2a bb00 1759 2ab4 0003
    0000010: 2ab4 0004 b700 18b5 000d 2ab4 0019 b800
    0000020: 1a99 000e 2ab4 000d 2ab4 0019 b600 1b2a
    0000030: b400 059e 000e 2ab4 000d 2ab4 0005 b600
    0000040: 1c2a b400 0699 002e 2abb 001d 592a b400
    0000050: 0a2a b400 0db6 001e 2ab4 000d b600 1f2a
    0000060: b400 0db6 0020 2ab4 000d b600 21b7 0022
    0000070: b500 07b1   Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@47)
    same_frame(@65)
    same_frame(@115) at com.signInventory.config.ProdDataSourceConfiguration.jedisConnectionFactory(ProdDataSourceConfiguration.java:46) at com.signInventory.config.ProdDataSourceConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$258faa2b.CGLIB$jedisConnectionFactory$8(<generated>) at com.signInventory.config.ProdDataSourceConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$258faa2b$$FastClassByCGLIB$$b4f3aedd.invoke(<generated>) at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:286) at com.signInventory.config.ProdDataSourceConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$258faa2b.jedisConnectionFactory(<generated>) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160) ... 37 more
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Had exactly the same problem when I upgraded to Spring Data Redis v1.2.1-RELEASE.  I solved the problem after upgrading Jedis to the latest version - v2.4.2.  If you are using Maven, check the following dependencies.

```
<properties>
    <spring.data.redis>1.2.1.RELEASE</spring.data.redis>
    <jedis>2.4.2</jedis>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.data.redis}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>${jedis}</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 6):

You need to add a reference to the apache commons-pool2 library. I had the same problem in a Scala project - we were using sbt, so it was just a case of adding:

```
"org.apache.commons" % "commons-pool2" % "2.0"
```

As you're using Java, you might be using Maven, so I would expect it's probably more like this (untested - take it with a pinch of salt!):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is a [JDK compiler bug #8006684](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8006684)

See also [taskdef java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack when TEAM CITY executes build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255261/taskdef-java-lang-verifyerror-bad-type-on-operand-stack-when-team-city-executes)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone facing it due to migration from Spring Boot 1.5.x to 2.x.x here is [thread](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12843) that explains it. Also please see this [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#redis)

> Lettuce is now used instead of Jedis as the Redis driver when
>   you use spring-boot-starter-data-redis. If you are using higher level
>   Spring Data constructs you should find that the change is transparent.
>
> We still support Jedis. Switch dependencies if you prefer Jedis by
>   excluding io.lettuce:lettuce-core and adding redis.clients:jedis
>   instead.
>
> Connection pooling is optional and, if you are using it, you now need
>   to add commons-pool2 yourself as Lettuce, contrary to Jedis, does not
>   bring it transitively.